# I insert a null column and in the next I save the data

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

because when I make a record in my form to the database first I register a null column and after the value that I insert, I am using spring

```
@RequestMapping("/listaPalabras")
public ModelAndView listaPalabras(Palabras uploadItem, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("listaPalabras");
    List<Palabras> list = palService.listPalabras();
    return new ModelAndView("listaPalabras", "list", list);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/agregarPalabras", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String productCreate(@ModelAttribute("palabra") Palabras palabras) {

    palService.saveOrUpdate(palabras);
    return "agregarPalabras";
```

}

[this is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3kYG.png)

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: can we see the palService.listPalabras() code ?. are you asking why your first record returns null fields ?